# Perl's JSON decode_json with JSON.stringify string

Tags: javascript, json, perl

I have a front-end and back-end script that are working with one another.  The front-end script of type JS does JSON.stringify on an array of strings and calls the backend script for validation on this string.

The backend script of type Perl grabs this string and does a decode_json from the Perl module JSON.  At this point the Perl script is croaking.

I think the problem has to do with what's returned by JSON.stringify.

JS:

```
var jl = ["Flash", "WonderWoman", "BatMan", "SuperMan", "GreenLantern", "MartianManHunter", "HawkWoman"];
var $jl_string = JSON.stringify(jl);

// assume there is code here that makes an AJAX call which calls the backend script
```

Returns this:

```
"[\"Flash\", \"WonderWoman\", \"BatMan\", \"SuperMan\", \"GreenLantern\", \"MartianManHunter\", \"HawkWoman\"]"
```

Perl function that validates the above stringified string:

```
sub are_jl_members {
    my ($jl_string) = @_;
    print "<p>$jl_string</p>";

    # Failing here.  Why?
    my $jl = decode_json $jl_string;
    print Dumper([$jl]);        
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume this is a typo, but you're mixing Perl and JavaScript in your first snippet.

Comment: I don't think so, what line?

Comment: `my $jl_string = JSON.stringify(jl);`

Comment: I can run that exact string through JSON::decode_json with no problems. And I can tell by inspection that JSON.stringify's output is correct. Are you sure there's no issue with the way you're getting the string that you feed to decode_json?

Comment: I think I found the problem. The string that is being passed as a param during the AJAX request includes the beginning and end quotes. So I end up with this error `garbage after JSON object, at character offset 3`.  How do I get around this?

Comment: You mean it literally includes those backslash-escaped quote marks?!

Comment: Yes it does.  I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the extra **"\"** in your `$jl_string`. Your JSON.stringify call is correct satanically.

How are you printing `$jl_string` here?

> Returns this:
>
> "[\"Flash\", \"WonderWoman\", \"BatMan\", \"SuperMan\", \"GreenLantern\", \"MartianManHunter\", \"HawkWoman\"]"